# Flutter: How to convert any String (without knowing image type) to Uint8List and use it for Image.memory?

Tags: flutter, image

I want to parse and convert any String without knowing the format (jpg, bmp, png etc.) to a processable format for Flutter to draw the corresponding image.

- I receive a `String` from the Backend, which is reflected as `snapshot.data` (because of a  FutureBuilder)
- The `String`s I receive have different formats, as you can see in my example image (see below)
- Mostly I do not know what is coming
- How can I safely parse the `String` and inject it as a `Uint8List` to my `Image.memory`-Widget?
- Also, why is my `BMP`-result corrupted? It should resemble a logo, but it shows an amazing glitch-artwork.

e.g. `BMP`-String starts with: BMC6(��B�������������
e.g. `JPG`-String starts with: ����JFIF``��C

[image]

Comment: Is the String coming as a base64?

Comment: @WilsonToribio no

Comment: Check http headers for content type

Comment: your question need more detail? String mean url of image, byte array, Uin8tlist or anything else?